# Flash Security Error #2048: Is there a workaround or does Twilio have to change their meta-policy?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, security, twilio

My Flash/Flex application is having a problem. For a few months it was able to download files from Twilio but now I'm getting the following error:

(I've had to remove hyperlinks, so imagine "ttp" is really "http". :)

> SecurityErrorEvent
>   type="securityError" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false eventPhase=2
>   text="Error #2048: Security sandbox
>   violation:
>   ttp://localhost/myapp.swf?v=1 cannot
>   load data from
>   ttp://api.twilio.com/."

I enabled policy logging on my flash plugin and get the following messages:

> OK: Searching for 
>   in policy files to authorize data
>   loading from resource at
>   ttp://api.twilio.com/
>   by requestor from
>   ttp://localhost/myapp.swf?v=1
>   Warning: [strict] Policy file
>   requested from
>   ttp://api.twilio.com/crossdomain.xml
>   redirected to
>   ttps://api.twilio.com/crossdomain.xml;
>   will use final URL in determining
>   scope. Warning: Domain api.twilio.com
>   does not specify a meta-policy.
>   Applying default meta-policy
>   'master-only'. This configuration is
>   deprecated. See
>   ttp://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files
>   to fix this problem. OK: Policy file
>   accepted:
>   ttps://api.twilio.com/crossdomain.xml
>   Error: Request for resource at
>   ttp://api.twilio.com
>   by requestor from
>   ttp://localhost/myapp.swf?v=1 is
>   denied due to lack of policy file
>   permissions.

So it looks to me like the problem is that Twilio doesn't specify a "meta-policy". Is there a way for me to get around this?

Comment: Can you email this to help@twilio.com as well so we can get someone looking into it?

Comment: When calling the API are you using `https://api.twilio.com` or `http://api.twilio.com`? HTTPS is required. That might be causing the error.

Comment: I sent these details to Rahim Sonawalla yesterday morning and haven't heard back. I was looking for a workaround in the interim.

Comment: I've tried both https and http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` and `twilio.com` are not in the same domain so of course you will get a security error. Twilio needs to add this node into the crossdomain:

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
```

Also, make sure your embedding is up to par:

```
allowscriptaccess = "always"
allownetworking = "all"
```

If Twilio won't update the crossdomain.xml then you can install a proxy on the server hosting your flex app and grab the data via your proxy.

Comment: Twilio updated their crossdomain.xml for me but the problem persists. I've taken the proxy route.

Comment: odd it looks like they took the crossdomain down completely they might be updating it or trying to figure out what the file does.

Comment: I have implemented the changes above, but am still getting a #2048, not using twillo.  Just working between my site and Rackspace cloudfiles CDN.  Adding the allow scripts and networking was not a problem.  site-control confused me a bit - I put this is a crossdomain.xml file and put this in the root of my site, is this accurate?

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2014, Twilio has added the necessary cross-domain permissions mentioned in this question.  If problems persist in this vein, please e-mail our support squad at help@twilio.com

Answer (score 0):

the response of  get crossdomain.xml must contain the HTTP response header "Content-Type:text/xml"