# ColdFusion websocket Flash fallback - not working

Tags: flash, coldfusion, cfwebsocket

I am using a ColdFusion 10 websockets to publish data to an application which all works fine for browsers that support webscockets. 
ColdFusion websockets are supposed to fallback to flash for browsers that do not support websockets (if they have flash enabled). 
I have enabled flash fallback in ColdFusion Administrator > websocket > Start Flash Policy Server . 
When I try and connect with a browser that doesn't support websockets, in this case IE9 (with flash enabled), no connection is formed and I get the following error :

```
[WebSocket] cannot connect to Web Socket server at 
ws://www.mydomain.com:8575/cfusion/cfusion (SecurityError: Error #2048)
make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed
```

I then tried accessing the same page (with IE9), however this time on my local ColdFusion server and it falls back to Flash without any problem!

I really can't figure out what is going. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but is the _Flash socket policy file correctly placed_ (is it accessible)?  The websocket is attempting to connect over port 8575; is that accessible?

Comment: [How can I fix a Flash security error #2048](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634366/how-can-i-fix-a-flash-security-error-2048)

Comment: I am actually not sure, I really don't have any experience with Flash Socket Policy Files. I just assumed this would be taken care of automatically since that appears to be what happened when I tested it on my local server..I never set up any Socket Policy files there and the fallback worked fine. Thanks for the link...I will try and get my head around it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this issue is resolved.

It turns out that the firewall on the server was blocking the port used for flash fallback !

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Thanks for coming back and answering.